# Color and inverted sentence?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, word-order, colloquialisms, subject-verb-inversion

One of my colleagues asked me the other day why can we say both the following?

> Red is my favorite color.

> My favorite color is red.

Yet, we cannot say

> Red is his house.

when his house is red.

What makes this possible for favorite color but not for a house for example?

Comment: "Red is his house's colour." - sounds a bit awkward but not wrong like "red is his house".

Comment: _Red is his house_ would only be used in poetic language (as in the song 'Black is the colour of my true love's hair'). But if you say _Red is my favourite colour_, 'red' is the subject and not just an adjective.

Comment: Note that in both of the sentences in the question, the word *colour* is used.